# Выбор случайного элемента из TableLayout

Tags: java, android

В этом коде создается подобие сетки размером Х на Х. Нужно, чтобы один элемент из этой таблицы был выбран случайно, и чтобы ему был присвоен другой цвет.

```
private void GrdidGenerate() {
    for (int i = 0; i < LevelGrid[pos]; i++) {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));
        for (int j = 0; j < LevelGrid[pos]; j++) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
            params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc_btn_radio_material);
            imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r, g, b));
            imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            tableRow.addView(imageView, j);
        }
        grid.addView(tableRow, i);
    }
}
```

Как присваивать цвет я знаю, но как выбрать случайный элемент из таблицы - нет.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Думаю, метод стоит переименовать хотя бы в `GridGenerate`. А лучше бы в `generateGrid`. По поводу самого вопроса: если я правильно понял, то в данном коде должен быть выбран случайный `imageView`. Так как он однозначно определяется с помощью `i` и `j`, то, например, можно сгенерировать два случайных числа от `0` до `LevelGrid[pos]` и устанавливать `imageView` другой цвет при соответствующих `i` и `j`.

Comment: вам нужно произвольно менять этот случайный элемент в уже сгенерированной таблице или выбрать его один раз при ее создании?

Comment: @Regent , я тоже так думал, но вот как мне обатиться к нужному ImageView если у него даже нету айди.

Comment: id устанавливается методом `imageView.setId(int id)`

Comment: @alex11 во внутреннем цикле к нему можно просто обратиться как `imageView`. Я, пожалуй, попытаюсь оформить это в качестве ответа. Особенно учитывая, что ответ PloadyFree добавляет цвет для целого столбца, а не для отдельной клетки

Comment: @pavlofff , просто таблица каждый раз меняется, и элемент должен быть случайным

Comment: Я тут подумал, если каждому элементу при создании присваивать ид imageView.setId("img_"+j+"_"+i); а потом можно было как-то элементу с этим ид присвоить цвет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, конечно, присваивать клеткам ID и менять цвет нужной клетке после цикла, но можно просто принимать решение о выборе цвета в каждой итерации.

Решение принимается на основании сравнения `i` и `j` с соответствующими случайными числами (`iRand` и `jRand`).

Схематичный пример со строками вместо таблицы:

```
int X = 10;
Random rand = new Random();
int iRand = rand.nextInt(X);
int jRand = rand.nextInt(X);
String[] grid = new String[X];
for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
{
    String row = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < X; j++)
    {
        String cell;
        if (i == iRand && j == jRand)
        {
            cell = "#";
        }
        else
        {
            cell = j + "";
        }
        row += cell + " ";
    }
    grid[i] = row;
}
```

[Пример в fiddle](http://goo.gl/6ZK39A).

Comment: Основную мысль уловил, но еще не полностью разобрался..

Comment: @alex11 в `if-else` должны быть `imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r1, g1, b1));` в `if` и `imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r, g, b));` в `else`. Со строками хорошо то, что в fiddle можно наглядно увидеть, как это работает.

Comment: уже все понял, спасибо.

Comment: @alex11 на здоровье.